# Cuda with cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cuda

I am trying to compile a existing CMake project using Cuda v8.0 that I found online. To do that, I use CMake GUI version. (I am currently running Windows 10, with Visual Studio 2017). The "Configure" step always givs me the following error message:

> No CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER could be found.

I have cuda 8.0 installed (altogether with other Cuda versions that I removed from my path), CuDNN also in my path. And I expect at some points to generate Visual studio project files that I could then use to compile the project...

What could cause that error?

#### EDIT

Upon request, I uploaded the CMakeOutput.log there : https://framabin.org/?c532b10d2a4aef54#NkJZItfUfPwMP6BHCiP5DhQS40duM4AhsKR+bWHN0tE=

Comment: Provide us with a short `CMakeLists.txt` you are using, an expect to be working, but doesn't. Then we might be able to comment. Also - which CMake version are you using?

Comment: I am using cmake 3.11.1. But the CMakelist is not mine (I am not comfortable with cmake).

Comment: We'll still need to see what it is your `CMakeLists.txt` is trying to do, that's failing. Link to it or post it here if it's short.

Comment: If it is any help on my case, It is mxnet that I am trying to compile. https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet

Comment: The error message you're getting is weird, since the file you linked to doesn't m ention that variable (`CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER`) and CMake itself does not seem to use it either. When you run cmake initially, it produces the files `CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log`. Can you upload them somewhere and link to them?

Comment: Yup, I was scratching my head for too long on this one... I pasted the CMakeOutput.log there : https://framabin.org/?c532b10d2a4aef54#NkJZItfUfPwMP6BHCiP5DhQS40duM4AhsKR+bWHN0tE= . The CMakeError.log is empty

Comment: @EmileD. I see the following line in your output: `nvcc fatal : 32 bit compilation is only supported for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and earlier`. You could try switching to VS2013.

Comment: Indeed! During my repeated experimentations, it slept back to 32 bits. I fixed it to compile it again on x64. But I am kind of surprised, because it seems that the Output message refers to Cuda v9.1. But I should be using v8.0. How did that happen?

Comment: Here is the new CMakeError.log: https://framabin.org/?8cd63891cf3a9aac#lFJurCF8dlRviQkri4QAi4uHvrjDj081BaXZP1JR7zY=

Comment: @EmileD. According to the output, the error is now `unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! Only the versions 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017 are supported!`. I guess you should try one of those. I'm not familiar with Windows so I can't test this myself unfortunately.

Comment: Ahh, I see the line that you are pointing out. But that's sad. I am using Visual Studio 2017... So it seems it is not fully supported in 2017... I also have the c++ 2015 compiler extension installed in it. Is it possible that this error message is a side-effect of another error, than when it percolates up on the call stack, it displays this error, but the source would be elsewhere?

Comment: I think the error comes from CUDA and not CMake. It is triggered by the line `#if _MSC_VER < 1600 || _MSC_VER > 1911` in `c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.1\include\crt/host_config.h`. You can try to find out your VS version and see if there is a mismatch. If you wanted to use a different version of CUDA, just point `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER` to the right path.

Comment: Well, I am using Visual Studio 2017 with version 15.7.1, so the version is _MSC_VER == 1914. So it might be the reason, indeed! I'll download the more recent version of Cuda. But I guess I'll have to worry if I may break Cuda at every update...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright! With @raul-laasner help, I think I have the solution of my problems!

1. The first one was indeed that my Cuda version was not correctly identified. And I am not sure at this stage that one was found at all. My environment variables where probably ignored also. I had to specify the CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER option to "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/bin/nvcc.exe".
2. Then, the problem was that I was using a too recent version of Visual Studio. For starters, Cuda v8.0 is not compatible with Visual Studio 2017: [Cuda 8.0 with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495565/cuda-8-0-with-visual-studio-2017). But even with the most recent version of Cuda, my Visual Studio is too recent. Meaning: NVIDIA lags behind when it comes to the Visual Studio versions... And now, Microsoft plans to update the _MSC_VER on most of the upgrade. Thus, I had two choices:

   - Downgrade Visual Studio to a compatible version.
   - Use more recent version of Cuda (9.2) and modify the c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include\crt\host_config.h to change the upper limit of the _MSC_VER verification.

By doing the second option, I managed to configure and compile the project. I am not sure though that I won't have later problems with this "hacky" way. But at least, I've been on a further step!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was caused by nvcc(x64 version) doesn't support x86 platform and was fixed by specifying the platform for cmake:

```
$build> cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```